# C# Validate Xdocument File

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xelement

I need to validate a selected Xml file using Xdocument without Xsd.
I have a file named "Cheker" and the file to check.
for example i need to compare the hierarchy ,and how much elements by name from the checker file.
if i have in the "checker" file 3 page i need to chek there is no more in the selected file.
I tried with a array but is to much complicated like this
thanks!!

```
            XElement pageElement = metadataFile.Root.Element("Pages");
            int cntPage = ((IEnumerable<XElement>)pageElement.Elements()).Count();
            if (cntPage < 1 || cntPage > 3) errorDetails += "Number of Pages wrong!!";
```

Comment: It is not too complicate, IMO. What way you expect to more simpler?

Comment: what the command for read the Xdocument and copy with the hierarchy into array,for checking the hierarchy and count specific elements?

Comment: It's probably helpful to show a short example of the XML file you're examining, and the code you used to construct the `metadataFile` element. Please consider editing your question to show these things.

Comment: this is a example of md file

Answer (score 0):

[`Elements()` already returns `IEnumerabl<XElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So the explicit cast on the second line of your code is unnecessary :

```
int cntPage = pageElement.Elements().Count();
```

Which style to use is a matter of preference here, but the entire code snippet can be re-written to be as follow :

```
int cntPage = metadataFile.Root
                          .Element("Pages")
                          .Elements()
                          .Count();
if (cntPage < 1 || cntPage > 3) 
    errorDetails += "Number of Pages wrong!!";
```